# Local storage not saving the checkbox unchecked stage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, local-storage

I am using jquery and local storage to save the state of a checkbox.

For saving I use:

```
function save_form() {
    window.localStorage.setItem('fb_show', $('#fb_show').val());
    alert('Saved');
}

function load_form() {
    var fb_checkbox_val = window.localStorage.getItem('fb_show');
    alert(fb_checkbox_val);

    if (fb_checkbox_val == 'on') {
        $("#fb_show").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $("#fb_show").prop("checked", false);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when it's unchecked it will save the value as 'on' so that part worked BUT when I uncheck the checkbox and save it again, it still saves as 'on' ... so the code after that will set it as checked again.

How can I fix this?

Comment: thats because you are saving the checkbox value, not it's state

Comment: @atmd I think that doesn't matter here!! OP might be setting the value of checkbox to `on` or `off` in on `checked` event and then hez comparing the `string` value not the bool value!

Comment: but the value remains the same if checked or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should save the **state** of the checkbox in `localStorage`:

```
function save_form() {
    window.localStorage.setItem('fb_show', $('#fb_show').is(':checked'));
    alert('Saved');
}

function load_form() {
    var fb_checkbox_val = window.localStorage.getItem('fb_show') === 'true' ? true : false;
    alert(fb_checkbox_val);

    $("#fb_show").prop("checked", fb_checkbox_val);
}
```

Comment: worth pointing out that saving a boolean value in storage will be converted to a string. (`"true"` not `true`)

Answer (score 0):

An unchecked checkbox doesn't actually have a value and therefore you have to check whether or not it is checked and save that value. `$("#fb_show").is(":checked")`